# Migration from Google Cloud SQL to Google Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

I need to migrate two of my tables from Google Cloud SQL to Google Bigquery.

The data is about 1 TB in size and about 5 months of stock market tick data.

I understand from the documentation, that I can export data as CSV and load it into Bigquery. I wish to do date-wise partitions in Google Bigquery, as suggested in best practices. Also, I wish to do a robust verification after each date's data is migrated, to be sure that data doesn't get corrupted during transfer.

My question is, how can I write code to do this loop over dates, and within each loop:
 1. export from Google Cloud SQL
 2. load into Google BigQuery
 3. Test that data has not got corrupted in transfer

Comment: I do not see an easy way to do all three steps on a loop. I understand that in each loop, you'd like to load into BQ, the exported csv resulted of: select * from table where day=SOME_DAY   I'd say that cannot be achieved programatically [only via UI](https://console.cloud.google.com/sql/instances/cloudsql/export). Have I understood correctly? Also, for the third step you'll basically need to check for returned errors on the batch load job results.

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly. I [see](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/exporting) that we cannot export CSV programmatically but we can export as SQL dump file using gcloud commandline tool. Can that dump be uploaded into bigquery programmatically?

Answer (score 3):

You can use BigQuery [Cloud SQL federated query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-sql-federated-queries) to copy Cloud SQL table into BigQuery. You can do it with one BigQuery SQL statement. For example, following SQL copy MySQL table sales_20191002 to BigQuery table demo.sales_20191002.

```
INSERT
   demo.sales_20191002 (column1, column2 etc..)
SELECT
   *
FROM
   EXTERNAL_QUERY(
      "project.us.connection",
      "SELECT * FROM sales_20191002;");
```

`EXTERNAL_QUERY("connection", "foreign SQL")` would execute the "foreign SQL" in the Cloud SQL database specified in "connection" and return result back to BigQuery. "foreign SQL" is the source database SQL dialect (MySQL or PostgreSQL).

Before running above SQL query, you need to create a BigQuery connection which point to your Cloud SQL database.

Finally, you can validate the data quality by checking some high level statistics of two tables. For example, does number of rows match? does group by result match?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do:

1. Export your table(s) in Cloud SQL to CSV
2. Upload those CSV files to Google Cloud Storage
3. Write a Cloud Dataflow pipeline to ingest the CSV files, and write to the correct partitions.
4. Use SQL in BigQuery to validate your data

Comment: Thanks. Can steps 1 and 2 be done programmatically? If so, please include code/link. Also, what SQL can verify data? Running this gives error

Comment: Also, what SQL can verify data? Running this gives error "SELECT MD5(bid_price) FROM [project:database.table]" like "MD5 does not exist" despite MD5 being [listed](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators) as a function.

Comment: The table has billions of rows, and I can't practically verify each data point. I want to be able to match MD5 or some other checksum of each column in both original and final bigquery tables.

Comment: Yes, all this can of course be done programmatically using each tools API and client libs. MD5 is working for you because you're using legacy SQL. Switch to standard SQL for it to work.

Comment: @Siddharth can you confirm the actual error it throws when using legacySQL is "Unrecognized function md5" and not "MD5 does not exist"?

Comment: @graham can you point me to where documentation to do step 1 and step 2 programatically?

Comment: @MarCialR yes, I was being lazy in not pasting actual error. After Graham's suggestion of switching to standard SQL, I stop getting that error, but start getting another error, but that's related to datatypes, I'll figure that out.

Comment: @SiddharthVerma 1 and 2 can be done in one API call using Cloud SQL (beta)  by specifying exportContext's [uri and csvExportOptions.selectQuery](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/instances/export)

Comment: @MarCialR this Cloud SQL(beta) stuff is great, I wouldn't have landed on it myself, thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry to jump in the discussion. I had problem exporting CSV. 

Here's my output after I exported using gcloud (2nd gen) tool

852,"00030","00030","ABADI JAYA,TK - WANGUK","ABADI JAYA,TK - WANGUK"

The delimiter is comma by default. There's comma in several cells on my database. It supposed to be 5 column, but Big Query read it as 7 column.

Graham Polley, do you mind to give some advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Setting aside the fact that I would probably also choose Dataflow for a task like this, I've been working on a python sample that does exactly what Siddharth asked for. I'd expect it to work well enough for small datasets.

It gathers a list of days from a source CloudSQL table. Then, for each day:

1) exports relevant CloudSQL rows into separate CSV files

2) loads each CSV into a separate BQ table and

3) launches a simple verification query both in MySQL and BQ

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  days = mysql_distinct_days()[:NUM_DAYS_TO_TEST]

  do_extract_and_load(days)

  do_checks(days)

  if DELETE_TABLES:
    delete_tables(days)
```

I've shared a [gist with the full source code and output](https://gist.github.com/MarCialR/0350da5b57052d700cfa5f3a8f6aac56) in hopes that it'll prove helpful to somebody down the road. :-)